# PHP representation of given JSON output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following JSON output after some mixing and matching:

```
{
    "tutor": 
    [
        {
            "tid": "1",
            "fname": "John",
            "lname": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "tid": "2",
            "fname": "Linda",
            "lname": "Jane"
        }
    ]
}
```

I currently have this PHP code - but it does not quite create the desired output - **what do I need to change for this to match the above JSON??**

```
    $test = array();
    $column = array();

    if($count > 0)
    {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $test[] =  array( 
                $column[] = array(
                            'tid'       => $row['TID'],
                            'fname'     => $row['FNAME'],
                            'lname'     => $row['LNAME']
                            );
                        );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for that other nesting, just push them inside the container and encode them:

```
$column = array();

if($count > 0) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $column[] = array(
            'tid'       => $row['TID'],
            'fname'     => $row['FNAME'],
            'lname'     => $row['LNAME']
        );            
    }
}

echo json_encode(array('tutor' => $column));
// echo json_encode(array('tutor' => $column), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // for PHP 5.4
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much - will accept as soon as I can :-)